# Sectioned UITableview parsed from XML file (need help structuring XML file)

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, parsing, uitableview

im trying to make a sectioned tableview which is passed from an XML file hosted on my server.

I already know a bit about parsing XML files into tableviews but im stuck on how im meant to structure an XML file so that it can be parsed. my table should look something like

```
[parentView]
- [section 1]
- - [item 1]
- - - [description]
- - - [price]
- - - [url]
- - [item 2]
- - - [description]
- - - [price]
- - - [url]
- [section 2]
- - [item 1]
- - - [description]
- - - [price]
- - - [url]
- - [item 2]
- - - [description]
- - - [price]
- - - [url]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would be ok. You can give the sections ids if you want to or you can just assign them when youre enumerating through the parsing. Same goes for the items.

This parser heres makes the parsing process really simple using "." syntax.

[Easy XML Parsing](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html)

```
   <parent>
    <section id="0">

    <item desc="describtion" price="0.0" url="something.com"/>
    <item desc="describtion" price="0.0" url="something.com"/>

    </section>

    <section id="1">

    <item desc="describtion" price="0.0" url="something.com"/>
    <item desc="describtion" price="0.0" url="something.com"/>

    </section>


    </parent>
```

Comment: also, can i give the sections Attributes? ie Title?

Comment: you can deffinately give the sections a title attribute. This will be seen in the handy little scroll bar of the sectioned table. You will probably have to parse your xml out into an nsdictionary to work the easiest with a sectioned tableview. This tutorial here helped me alot. Theres no xml parsing in it put it will show you how you will have to represent your xml data to be consumed by the table http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-indexed-table-view.html

Comment: ok thanks for this, what if i wanted to go one level deeper, would that be acheivable too?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the XML format in the first place, you could simply format it as a property list, you can the use the built in parsing methods to load it for you straight into arrays, dictionaries etc. You can see the plist format in the apple docs, I'm on the phone ATM so it's a bit hard to put a link here.

Your base element would be an array (one element per section), each element would be an array of dictionaries (one dictionary per row in your section).